# Is there a workaround for flex generating YY_NEW_FILE

Tags: g++

flex 2.6.4

g++ (GCC) 11.3.0

Win 11-x64

Cygwin

I do buffer switching in my scanner. During the 'old' days YY_NEW_FILE was generated by flex. This is now obsolete, Flex 2.6.4 manual,  Chapter, 12 End-of-File Rules pg. 38, "• assigning yyin to a new input file (in previous versions of flex, after doing the assignment you had to call the special action YY_NEW_FILE. This is no longer necessary". Flex generates YY_NEW_FILE references in the code but Flex has
#define YY_NEW_FILE yyrestart( yyin  )

preceding the two references (below). I use g++ -c -std=C++11  for the compile but the #define doesn't seem to work.

A similar issue occurs with YY_DO_BEFORE_ACTION. The #define is not expanded by g++.

Any idea what I've done wrong?

thanks;

code fragments
case EOB_ACT_END_OF_FILE:
{
(yy_did_buffer_switch_on_eof) = 0;

```
            if ( yywrap(  ) )
                {
                /* Note: because we've taken care in
                 * yy_get_next_buffer() to have set up
                 * yytext, we can now set up
                 * yy_c_buf_p so that if some total
                 * hoser (like flex itself) wants to
                 * call the scanner after we return the
                 * YY_NULL, it'll still work - another
                 * YY_NULL will get returned.
                 */
                (yy_c_buf_p) = (yytext_ptr) + YY_MORE_ADJ;

                yy_act = YY_STATE_EOF(YY_START);
                goto do_action;
                }

            else
                {
                if ( ! (yy_did_buffer_switch_on_eof) )
                    YY_NEW_FILE;
                }
            break;
```

and

```
            case EOB_ACT_END_OF_FILE:
                {
                if ( yywrap(  ) )
                    return 0;

                if ( ! (yy_did_buffer_switch_on_eof) )
                    YY_NEW_FILE;
```